# Blender 3.0: Warning colors on faces of object on extrude

Tags: modeling, extrude

[image: In Blender 3.0, warning colors on faces appear as you extrude planes. I've never seen this in other versions. Please clarify.]

> In Blender 3.0, warning colors on faces appear as you extrude planes. Also occurs when moving planes. I've never seen this in other versions and can't find documentation on this enhancement. Please clarify.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like you have enabled the [*Mesh Analysis*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/mesh_analysis.html#mesh-analysis) overlay.

[image]

Simply disable the overlay in the viewport header to view the object as normal.